# Laravel dompdf view didnot match with blade view

Tags: laravel, foreach, html-table, dompdf

I got problem with Laravel DOMPDF and i dont know where is mistake

this my blade view
[image]

this my pdf view
[image]

this my foreach code loop

```
             @foreach ($hari as $hr)
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="{{ $data->where('hari', $hr['id'])->count() }}" class="align-middle text-center">
                        <center>{{ $hr['hari'] }}</center>
                    </td>
                    @foreach ($data->where('hari', $hr['id']) as $item)
                        <td>
                            {{ $item->pelajaran->nama }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $item->ruangan->nama }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $item->guru->nama }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ substr($item->mulai, 0, -3) }} - {{ substr($item->selesai, 0, -3) }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

I dont know where is my mistake, please help to solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried to `CTRL + P` your page to see what it suppose to look like?

Comment: it just same view good in blade view, looks messy in pdf view

Comment: Have try changing your `@foreach` location?

Comment: i have switch foreach position and not use condition when do foreach, but the result is not even what I want

Answer (score 0):

your first @endforeach wrong position

Comment: can you tell the writing of the foreach ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `@foreach`

```
@foreach ($hari as $hr)
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="{{ $data->where('hari', $hr['id'])->count() }}" class="align-middle text-center">
                    <center>{{ $hr['hari'] }}</center>
                </td>
                @foreach ($data->where('hari', $hr['id']) as $item)
                    <td>
                        {{ $item->pelajaran->nama }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $item->ruangan->nama }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $item->guru->nama }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ substr($item->mulai, 0, -3) }} - {{ substr($item->selesai, 0, -3) }}
                    </td>
                 @endforeach
                </tr>
        @endforeach
```

try changing this in your `dompdf config` file change the `"dpi" => 96` to `"dpi" => 196`

Comment: i try this but the result is the same

Comment: is there an html `<table>` tag in your code?

Comment: sure, i put <table>,<thead>and <tbody> and loop i put in <tbody>

Comment: try adding `style="table-layout:fixed;"` in your `<table>` tag

Comment: I'm tired of this problem and i will use windows.print()
thank you so much for trying so hard to help me

Comment: no problem I'm sorry for not being able to help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
            @foreach ($hari as $hr)
            @foreach ($data->where('hari', $hr['id']) as $key => $item)
                <tr>
                  @if($key == 0)
                    <td rowspan="{{ $data->where('hari', $hr['id'])->count() }}" class="align-middle text-center">
                        <center>{{ $hr['hari'] }}</center>
                    </td>
                   @endif
                        <td>
                            {{ $item->pelajaran->nama }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $item->ruangan->nama }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $item->guru->nama }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ substr($item->mulai, 0, -3) }} - {{ substr($item->selesai, 0, -3) }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).